# Reactor spring mongodb repository combine multiple results together

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactor-netty

I'm kind of new to reactive programing and currently working on a spring webflux based application. I'm stuck between few questions.

```
public class FooServiceImpl {

@Autowired
private FooDao fooDao;

@Autowired
private AService aService;

@Autowired
private BService bService;

public long calculateSomething(long fooId) {
    Foo foo = fooDao.findById(fooId); // Blocking call one

    if (foo == null) {
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    Long bCount = bService.getCountBByFooId(fooId); // Blocking call two
    AEntity aEntity = aService.getAByFooId(fooId);  // Blocking call three

    // Do some calculation using foo, bCount and aEntity
    // ...
    // ...

    return someResult;
}
}
```

This is the way we write a blocking code which uses three external API call results (let's consider as DB calls). I'm struggling to convert this into a reactive code, If all three becomes mono and if I subscribe all three will the outer subscriber get blocked?

```
public Mono<Long> calculateSomething(long fooId) {
    return Mono.create(sink -> {
        Mono<Foo> monoFoo = fooDao.findById(fooId); // Reactive call one
        monoFoo.subscribe(foo -> {
            if (foo == null) {
                foo = new Foo();
            }

            Mono<Long> monoCount = bService.getCountBByFooId(fooId);  // Reactive call two

            monoCount.subscribe(aLong -> {
                Mono<AEntity> monoA = aService.getAByFooId(fooId);  // Reactive call three
                monoA.subscribe(aEntity -> {
                    //...
                    //...
                    sink.success(someResult);
                });
            });
        });
    };
  }
```

I saw there is a function called zip, but it only works with two results, So is there a way to apply it here?

Also what will happen if we get subscribe for something inside create method, Will it block the thread?

Would be very thankful if you could help me.

Comment: you should not subscribe, the subscriber is the calling client that initated the call, your service is a publisher, the client is the subscriber. If you wish to get the value and transform it you should instead use flatMap, and if you wish to do blocking calls you should put these on their own scheduler as described here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

Comment: every `subscribe` you do is blocking, so never subscribe (almost, there are som edge cases)

Comment: please look up a tutorial on youtube or something to understand how to write a basic webflux application.

Comment: Thank you very much @ThomasAndolf. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you gave me the calculation you want you do with those values, it would be easier for me to show the reactor way of doing it. But lets suppose you want to read a value from database and then use that value for another thing. Use flatmaps and make a unique Flux reducing the lines of code and complexity, no need to use subscribe() as told by the other people. Example:

```
return fooDao.findById(fooId)
.flatmap(foo -> bService.getCountBByFooId(foo))
.flatmap(bCount -> aService.getAByFooId(fooId).getCount()+bCount);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for showing it out, So if we want to combine few and transform `map()` and `flatmap()` are the way to go right?

Comment: Also to run the callback event on another thread we should use `Schedulers` right?
That means if we don't call with a `Scheduler` the caller thread will get blocked at the point of the `subscribe` till the `onNext` callback method is called, isn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Reading more found out the Reactor provides a method called `publishOn` to process on a different thread for blocking APIs.